# Get String From Array to call method

Tags: objective-c, c

I'm trying to get a string in my call from an array. But have no luck. It's being passed to another class.

```
MainClass.h
#import First
@class First;

@interface MainClass : UIViewController{
NSMutableArray *listArray;
}
///////////////////
MainClass.m

    First *first = [[First alloc] init];

    listArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [listArray addObject:@"first"];
        [listArray addObject:@"second"];

    int Aslot = 0;
    int sumA;
float level = 5, insample = 10;

    NSString *slotA =[listArray objectAtIndex:ASlot];

           sumA = [slotA out:insample andlevels:level];

/////////
First.h
-(float)out:(float)insample andlevels:(float)level;

First.m
-(float)out:(float)insample andlevels:(float)level{

float outsample = insample + 10 * level;

return outsample;
}
```

I want slotA (the Class) to equal a string from the array "first" or "second", so it can call the method.

I have a table which when I select first, it sends samples and other parameters to another class where it does processing then returns back to MainClass.

sumA = [first out:insample andlevels:level];

But I'm getting an error saying that NSString may not respond to my parameters out:andlevels. Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

If I understand correctly, you want to dynamically create an instance of a class whose name you have stored as an `NSString`.  You can do that this way:

```
int Aslot = 0;
int sumA;
float level = 5, insample = 10;

NSString *className = [listArray objectAtIndex:Aslot];
Class sampler = objc_getClass([className UTF8String]);
id instance = [[sampler alloc] init];
sumA = [instance out:insample andlevels:level];

// Do whatever you want with sumA here.

[instance release];
```

If you're doing this a lot, you'll probably want to either keep the instance around or store the classes in the array instead of their names, depending on exactly what you are doing.

Comment: So how would I be able to get the class name into the Method from an array??

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are trying to do.  What does `out:andlevels:` do?  How is it defined?  What is `insample`?  What is `level`?

Comment: Almost @Jim, "Aslot" is the objectindex which pulls the class out of the array sends it to the call when user makes selection, Not the whole array of classes. I tried adding a protocol but still was getting errors also objc_getClass(Const char* name) so UTF8String didn't work.

Comment: "getting errors" and "didn't work" is not helpful feedback.  What errors are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for the Help Jim, in .h I added the @protocol Class <NSObject> @end then @interface MainClass:UIViewController<Class>, Error: Use of undeclared identifier 'UTF8String', Error: "Receiver type 'Class*' is not 'id' or interface pointer, consider casting it to 'id', Error: Instance method '-alloc' not found(return type defaults to 'id')..... I overlooked Madhu post he was using if statements and it worked by changing self to the Class. But a lot more coding when adding more Classes.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, I'm trying to figure it out but i'm getting (null) from Class sampler = objc_getClass([className UTF8String]); className is outputting.

Comment: Objective C, like most programming languages, is case-sensitive.  Have you got @"first" or @"First" in the array?

Comment: lowercase @"first". NSLog(@"className: %@", className); Returning (Null). I've been trying other ways but doesn't work, like casting a Class.. Class sampler = (Class)objc_getClass([className UTF8String]);

Comment: Look at your code.  Your class is named `First`.  Using @"first" to try to load it won't work.  Objective C is case-sensitive.

Comment: Oh my!!! That WORKED. WOW!! Thank you soooo much Jim. I knew I was doing something wrong

Comment: why not use `Class sampler = NSClassFromString(className);`
`